# How do i open a ics file from javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

I am creating a mobile app. i have tried to open the .ics in an e-mail with success but i need to open it from javascript. I copied the file to my project's www/ics folder and i tried this:

```
window.location = "ics/callelement.ics";
```

Nothing happens. Maybe its because i cannot have ics files in my project in which case how do i go about getting the file?

Comment: [FYI, for those that do not know, an `ics` file is an `iCalendar` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar). That said, what happens if you access the path directly with the android browser?

Comment: In the simulator, android browser just opens as a txt file which is not what i want but am hoping this wont happen on the device. iPhone adds the event to the native calendar

Comment: Does your webserver send the correct headers? (`Content-type: text/calendar`)

Comment: there is no webserver - everything is done client side. Do i still need to declare Content-type: text/calendar

Comment: My alternative is to have a webserver sending the file to the client but i would rather avoid this if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to open an ics file by doing the following:

```
window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(calendarReminders.getFullCalendar()));
```

calendarReminders.getFullCalendar() returns a string that represents a valid iCalendar file.

Comment: I havent tried this since it was too long ago but i think this might work so i will mark as correct answer.